# ¿Cómo separar elementos de este array?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este array:

```
[ 5, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0]
```

Quiero separar en array diferentes los indices que su valor sea 0 es decir [ 1,7,9] , los que tengan valor 1 que serian [2,3,6] y finalmente lo que sean mayores de 1,  es decir [0,4,8]. tengo este código pero no me ha funcionado.

```javascript
NF= []
NT= []
NC= []
var num = [ 5, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0]

for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
if (num[i]=0) {  
    NC.push(num[0]);
}else if (num[i]=1) {
    NT.push(num[0]);
} else if (num[i]>1) 
    NF.push(num[0]);
};
```

Comment: Usas un ciclo con una variable `i` para ir aumentando las posiciones pero nunca la usas; `num[i]`. Para comparar usar doble igual; `==`

Comment: ya he cambiado esta indicacion, pero agrego a cada array nuevo el numero que corresponde, que serial el indice que corresponde, gracias

Comment: Es una confusión común. Un igual es asignación, 2 iguales son comparación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías usar [**`==`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) en vez de [**`=`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) en tus condicionales, ya que `==` es un operador de comparación, y `=` es un operador de asignación:

```
for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  if (num[0] == 0) {
    NC.push(num[0]);
  } else if (num[0] == 1) {
    NT.push(num[0]);
  } else if (num[0] > 1)
    NF.push(num[0]);
};
```

Ahora veo que siempre estas pusheando el mismo valor (posición 0), y lo que quieres es separar los indices del array dependiendo al valor que recibas, fácilmente te podrías apoyar de tu iterador `i` del `for` en vez de utilizar siempre la posición `[0]` de tu array, así:

```
for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  if (num[i] == 0) {
    NC.push(i);
  } else if (num[i] == 1) {
    NT.push(i);
  } else if (num[i] > 1) {
    NF.push(i);
  }
}
```

Código:

```js
var NF = [];
var NT = [];
var NC = [];
var num = [5, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0];

for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  if (num[i] == 0) {
    NC.push(i);
  } else if (num[i] == 1) {
    NT.push(i);
  } else if (num[i] > 1) {
    NF.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(NF);
console.log(NT);
console.log(NC);
```

Comment: fenomeno, gracias

Comment: A usted, saludos.